# Retain public access to files when using Google Cloud Storage Transfer Service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-transfer

I use Google Cloud Storage Transfer Service to move files between Google cloud buckets. I've actually executed one transfer job. In the source bucket there were files with enabled public access. In the destination bucket the same files no longer had public access.
**Is it possible to use transfer service and retain public access?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is no way to achieve this with the transfer service UI, you can use the `gsutil rsync -p` command to achieve this as mentioned in this [documentation file](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync#copying-in-the-cloud-and-metadata-preservation).

I would recommend you to set up a script in a cron rather than a transfer service to copy your files if you need to schedule this, or use the cloud shell if you are only gonna run this once

Comment: Using the CLI tool would do the job. What I don't like is that you cannot choose the output format (e.g. JSON). And if it is not a one-time thing, having structured output is really important.
Anyways, I think that you confirmed that transfer jobs cannot be used.